# Using CSS properties as input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display the current background colour of a container in an input. The JQuery I'm using doesn't work though, any ideas?

```
$('#custom-prev').attr('value', '$(.preview).css("background")');
```

Comment: Could you provide your markup?  The answers below are all based on the belief that you have defined the css property on the element itself.  If that is the case, you're golden.  If not, and you are trying to get the style based on your stylesheet(s), you'll need to do something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#custom-prev').val($('.preview').css("background-color"));
```

If you want it as setted in attribute style, use that:

```
$('#custom-prev').val($('.preview')[0].style.backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `$(.preview).css("background")` and also you need quotes around `.preview` inside the jquery selector: `$('.preview').css("background")`

```
$('#custom-prev').attr('value', $('.preview').css("background"));
```

Comment: selector should be a string

Comment: Use `.val()`, not `.attr('value')`

Comment: Yup roasted got that answer already right after I submitted my answer. I suggest his, but this one works too. At least I'm explaining what he did wrong.